# using POP/IMAP email serverpush notification to web server php

Tags: php, imap, pop3

i am working in emails i need push notification when inbox gets any emails 
simply i don't wants run any cron job directly gmail, outlook, yahoo ,Thunderbird etc notify my php server when new email in inbox please let me know that how i can do this

Comment: Have you try "Anything" yet ?

Comment: if you are saving emails in db (that u must do) then you need to check table entry each time like every 5 sec if table entry increase you can show notification to user that he got new email.

Comment: ofcourse there should be sender id receiver id and email id in that table

Comment: fetching details from server, storing into database and every time checking periodically is not efficient(is like cron job). can u provide some details in php which gives me real time update of emails by ping or pushing some details to my web server